# carto giving error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: carto

I have a new ubuntu 17.10 server that Im building an Open Streetmap Server on.  I installed carto and am now getting this error:

```
    osm@atlantageek-System-Product-Name:~/openstreetmap-carto-2.41.0$ carto project.mml > style.xml
/usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:19
    if (mapnik_reference.version.hasOwnProperty(version)) {
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object.ref.setVersion (/usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:19:33)
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:209:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/carto/lib/carto/tree/reference.js:213:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Im running node 8.2.1

Comment: and how did you solve it finally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue but with carto-vl not receiving the correct stats data from windshaft. Mine was solved by adding `layerStats: true` to the bottom of my windshaft config (`windshaft-folder/config/environments/development.js`)

E.g:

`,enabledFeatures: {
    ...
    layerStats: true, 
    ...
}`

It seems this used to be an optional flag that some clients now require (unfortunately this doesn't seem to be mentioned in any upgrade guides, so I had to dig around in code a bit)

Without more knowledge of how you installed, your issue may well be different.

Hope that helps!